# synchronise x-axis in multiplot

Tags: gnuplot, vertical-alignment

I am trying to plot several sets of data one on top of the other and I am trying to draw some vertical lines to represent some markers in each plot. The problem is with aligning these marker lines. For all the plots the x axis starts from 0 to a different maximum value for each plot.

Compiling the script below, one obtains an example of my problem. There are two blue dashed lines in the left of each plot which start from the same x coordinate and I my mind they should be aligned vertically. For the black lines on the left there is no need because the maximum value is different there. The question is: why aren't the blue dashed lines aligned and how can I make them aligned?

```
mpl_top    = 0.2 #inch  outer top margin, title goes here
mpl_bot    = 0.6 #inch  outer bottom margin, x label goes here
mpl_left   = 1.3 #inch  outer left margin, y label goes here
mpl_right  = 0.2 #inch  outer right margin, y2 label goes here
mpl_height = 3.0 #inch  height of individual plots
mpl_width  = 4.5 #inch  width of individual plots
mpl_dx     = 0.1 #inch  inter-plot horizontal spacing
mpl_dy     = 0.5 #inch  inter-plot vertical spacing
mpl_ny     = 2   #number of rows
mpl_nx     = 1   #number of columns

# calculate full dimensions
xsize = mpl_left+mpl_right+(mpl_width*mpl_nx)+(mpl_nx-1)*mpl_dx
ysize = mpl_top+mpl_bot+(mpl_ny*mpl_height)+(mpl_ny-1)*mpl_dy

# placement functions
#   rows are numbered from bottom to top
bot(n) = (mpl_bot+(n-1)*mpl_height+(n-1)*mpl_dy)/ysize
top(n)  = 1-((mpl_top+(mpl_ny-n)*(mpl_height+mpl_dy))/ysize)
#   columns are numbered from left to right
left(n) = (mpl_left+(n-1)*mpl_width+(n-1)*mpl_dx)/xsize
right(n)  = 1-((mpl_right+(mpl_nx-n)*(mpl_width+mpl_dx))/xsize)

set terminal postscript eps enhanced color dl 2.0 size xsize,ysize "Helvetica" 28
set encoding iso_8859_1
set tics scale 1.5

set output 'test.eps'
#
set offsets
set autoscale fix
set size 1,1
set nokey
#
set multiplot
#
set lmargin at screen left(1)
set rmargin at screen right(1)
#
set tmargin at screen top(2)
set bmargin at screen bot(2)
#.....................................................
#.....................................................
#
set origin 0.0,0.0
set xrange [0.0:79.739]
set yrange [-1.1:1.1]
set format x
set ylabel "z-z_0 ({\305})" font ",36"
set format y "%-2.2f"
set ytics
set mytics
#
set arrow 19 from first 7.5, first 0 to first 72.239, first 0 nohead dt 2 lw 2 lc 0
set arrow 29 from first 7.5, graph 0 to first 7.5, graph 1 nohead dt 2 lw 2 lc rgb "blue"
set arrow 39 from first 72.239, graph 0 to first 72.239, graph 1 nohead dt 2 lw 2 lc 0
set arrow 49 from first 19.215, graph 0 to first 19.215, graph 1 nohead dt 2 lw 2 lc rgb "blue"
set arrow 59 from first 58.5715, graph 0 to first 58.5715, graph 1 nohead dt 2 lw 2 lc 0
#
plot '9pto.dat' u 1:(column(1)-column(2)) w p pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "red"
#-----------------------------------------------
#
#========================9pto================================
#
unset arrow 19
unset arrow 29
unset arrow 39
unset arrow 49
unset arrow 59
#
#========================7pto================================
# 
#-----------------------------------------------
set lmargin at screen left(1)
set rmargin at screen right(1)
#
set tmargin at screen top(1)
set bmargin at screen bot(1)
#.....................................................
unset xrange
unset yrange
unset y2range
unset ylabel
unset y2label
unset ytics
unset y2tics
unset my2tics
#.....................................................
#
set origin 0.0,0.0
set xrange [0.0:71.427]
set yrange [-1.1:1.1]
set format x
set ylabel "z-z_0 ({\305})" font ",36"
set format y "%-2.2f"
set ytics
set mytics
#
set arrow 17 from first 7.5, first 0 to first 63.927, first 0 nohead dt 2 lw 2 lc 0
set arrow 27 from first 7.5, graph 0 to first 7.5, graph 1 nohead dt 2 lw 2 lc rgb "blue"
set arrow 37 from first 63.927, graph 0 to first 63.927, graph 1 nohead dt 2 lw 2 lc 0
set arrow 47 from first 19.215, graph 0 to first 19.215, graph 1 nohead dt 2 lw 2 lc rgb "blue"
set arrow 57 from first 50.2595, graph 0 to first 50.2595, graph 1 nohead dt 2 lw 2 lc 0
#
plot '7pto.dat' u 1:(column(1)-column(2)) w p pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "red"
#-----------------------------------------------
#
#========================7pto================================
# 
unset multiplot
```

The 9pto.dat is as follows:

```
 7.500000000    7.5000000000000
 7.500000000    7.5000000000000
 9.452500000    9.4525000000000
 9.452500000    9.4525000000000
 9.452500000    9.4525000000000
11.583156599    11.405000000000
11.539727382    11.405000000000
13.596201524    13.357500000000
13.536332124    13.357500000000
13.536332124    13.357500000000
15.716136896    15.310000000000
15.609405439    15.310000000000
17.730589548    17.262500000000
17.577538550    17.262500000000
17.577538550    17.262500000000
19.942432455    19.215000000000
19.696399454    19.215000000000
21.853782286    21.130916000000
21.613241577    20.806748000000
21.613241577    20.806748000000
23.951367855    23.371000000000
23.675253265    22.897216000000
25.876028840    25.286916000000
25.652539079    24.962748000000
25.652539079    24.962748000000
27.981455855    27.527000000000
27.700588520    27.053216000000
29.901766287    29.442916000000
29.673917026    29.118748000000
29.673917026    29.118748000000
32.015564739    31.683000000000
31.728849366    31.209216000000
33.935280551    33.598916000000
33.711807047    33.274748000000
33.711807047    33.274748000000
36.043972335    35.839000000000
35.760577517    35.365216000000
37.962737205    37.754916000000
37.735787279    37.430748000000
37.735787279    37.430748000000
40.076026405    39.995000000000
39.789136095    39.521216000000
41.995165304    41.910916000000
41.771451945    41.586748000000
41.771451945    41.586748000000
44.104011430    44.151000000000
43.820512338    43.677216000000
46.022759682    46.066916000000
45.795460028    45.742748000000
45.795460028    45.742748000000
48.136073388    48.307000000000
47.849254547    47.833216000000
50.056153041    50.222916000000
49.831177787    49.898748000000
49.831177787    49.898748000000
52.166378677    52.463000000000
51.883485575    51.989216000000
54.072515581    54.378916000000
53.849825503    54.054748000000
53.849825503    54.054748000000
56.210825315    56.619000000000
55.904445477    56.145216000000
58.071242482    58.571500000000
57.894686723    58.571500000000
57.894686723    58.571500000000
60.260074125    60.524000000000
60.099923105    60.524000000000
62.215148559    62.476500000000
62.119379597    62.476500000000
62.119379597    62.476500000000
64.312509506    64.429000000000
64.237663656    64.429000000000
66.335699265    66.381500000000
66.265901323    66.381500000000
66.265901323    66.381500000000
68.348020041    68.334000000000
68.359113309    68.334000000000
70.495709175    70.286500000000
70.423033245    70.286500000000
70.423033245    70.286500000000
72.195364598    72.239000000000
72.542252421    72.239000000000
```

And the 7pto.dat file is:

```
 7.500000000    7.5000000000000
 7.500000000    7.5000000000000
 9.452500000    9.4525000000000
 9.452500000    9.4525000000000
 9.452500000    9.4525000000000
11.570027646    11.405000000000
11.528708226    11.405000000000
13.575782705    13.357500000000
13.513624522    13.357500000000
13.513624522    13.357500000000
15.677771574    15.310000000000
15.586498468    15.310000000000
17.700850877    17.262500000000
17.547059322    17.262500000000
17.547059322    17.262500000000
19.888641959    19.215000000000
19.678988604    19.215000000000
21.803504020    21.130916000000
21.596035886    20.806748000000
21.596035886    20.806748000000
23.873441618    23.371000000000
23.640802845    22.897216000000
25.807281382    25.286916000000
25.618453971    24.962748000000
25.618453971    24.962748000000
27.871056796    27.527000000000
27.641136558    27.053216000000
29.799548044    29.442916000000
29.605761869    29.118748000000
29.605761869    29.118748000000
31.867722758    31.683000000000
31.637509864    31.209216000000
33.793129515    33.598916000000
33.592025117    33.274748000000
33.592025117    33.274748000000
35.870634350    35.839000000000
35.636214996    35.365216000000
37.804791496    37.754916000000
37.605887777    37.430748000000
37.605887777    37.430748000000
39.885438407    39.995000000000
39.649447834    39.521216000000
41.818678704    41.910916000000
41.616398208    41.586748000000
41.616398208    41.586748000000
43.903726004    44.151000000000
43.665404575    43.677216000000
45.824542985    46.066916000000
45.630606451    45.742748000000
45.630606451    45.742748000000
47.935779735    48.307000000000
47.672861008    47.833216000000
49.824715050    50.259500000000
49.673951259    50.259500000000
49.673951259    50.259500000000
51.987893623    52.212000000000
51.855902368    52.212000000000
53.965761583    54.164500000000
53.884656301    54.164500000000
53.884656301    54.164500000000
56.057317126    56.117000000000
55.987281835    56.117000000000
58.080894317    58.069500000000
58.010422067    58.069500000000
58.010422067    58.069500000000
60.105273987    60.022000000000
60.105270232    60.022000000000
62.246754237    61.974500000000
62.167660596    61.974500000000
62.167660596    61.974500000000
63.942897335    63.927000000000
64.295080389    63.927000000000
```

I am not sure how to attach data files so I am sorry to the length of this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please think again: The blue lines are located at the same x position with`from first 7.5`, `from first 19.215`.  The coordinate system `first` is defined by the x and y axes. You have different x axes. So, there is no real reason for the blue lines to be aligned.

To align the lines, there are several possibilities:

- Use a coordinate system which does not depend on the x axis: `graph` or `screen`
- Keep the `first` coordinate system and use the same x range everywhere (I think this might be the preferred solution.)
- Keep the `first` coordinate system and the different x ranges and recalculate the x position for each plot such that the lines are aligned

Comment: I thought that `first` coordinate system used the x axis values and since all my x axes started from 0 I thought that at least the beginning should be the same. I now realise that there is an issue with the aspect ration that makes this impossible. I don't know how to precisely position a line using `graph` or `screen` coordinate system